# Single Orchard CMS site for multiple websites or installation for each

Tags: orchardcms

Since orchard is database driven, It seems like one orchard installation could be hosted in IIS with multiple domain bindings and have each domain pull it's own content. But it doesn't appear this is the case. I have to create new IIS websites for each orchard installation. It seems very redundant to have all these websites with the exact same underlying content.

How could I setup one Orchard website in IIS and have many domains that point to it have unique content and themes?

Forgive my ignorance with this if it's blatant, but I just got done with a week long adventuring evaluating WordPress and running into the same issue. So my fuse is a little short with Orchard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Orchard sites can be set up in a multi-tenant configuration:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Setting-up-a-multi-tenant-orchard-site

Comment: Yup. I run 3 sites myself on a single instance, and some of my customers do the same. It works.

Comment: I confirm this, and moreover multi-tenancy also works well if you deploy Orchard on Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Even without using multiple Orchard tenants the *Rewrite Rules* module can be used to redirect different domains or subdomains to different addresses inside your site.

In the site configuration I was able to add a comma-separated list of hosts (since I had multi-tenancy enabled I did this in Tenancy / Default / Host).

After installing the Rewrite Rules module I added the rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www\.)?shooting\-?coach\.de)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/+.*$ http://harald-muehlhoff.de/fotograf/ [R=302,L]
```

to redirect all traffic from *[www.]shooting[-]coach.de[/something]* to *harald-muehlhoff.de/fotograf/* ignoring the initial request uri. Obviously your requirements may differ but hopefully this example will get you started!

Comment: I actually need a solution similar to this, however this doesn't apply for Orchard 1.8 anymore... (might be related to the Rewrite Rules module). `Invalid path for child request 'http://www.domain.com/path/'. A virtual path is expected.` @Line 21:                     httpContext.Server.TransferRequest(Url, true); `TransferResult.cs`